Using the 'event' details of onMouseEnter causes re-renders which overpower onMouseLeave functions in React
I want to create spans of text that show a preview of an image when you mouse over them.
What should happen is that when the mouse hovers over the section, the show boolean state is set to true and the location of the mouse must be used to position the preview element. This code looks like this.


    const Graphic = ({item,text})=>{
        const handleHover = (event)=>{
            setPreviewGraphic(x=>item);
            setShowPreview(true);
            setPreviewLoc([event.pageX,event.pageY])
        }
        return (

            <span className='graphic' 
                onMouseOver={handleHover}
                onMouseOut={()=>{setShowPreview(false);}}
            >{text}</span>
        )
    }

The issue is that setShowPreview(false) never registers as setShowPreview(true) is being called 60 times a second because setPreviewLoc([event.pageX,event.pageY]) causes a re-render.
I don't know of a better way to get the desired effect.
I tried using getBoundingClientRect() of the span. However, if the span covers a line break then the Rect is massive. Plus it doesn't appear where the mouse is.
Is there some way to accomplish this effect that I'm missing?

I'd encourage you to edit the question, break the setStates into their own lines to make this readable and show the entire component where you actually declare the state variables. That way I can give a full answer. However, off the top of my head, you might want to use onMouseEnter, that way setShowPreview doesnt get called repeatedly

After having a sleep and reading what you said. As I looked back at the code to write out the context I realized context was the issue.  I declared the component within the parent component. Old python habits where you can nest functions without issue. So each time the parent component was called from the mouse event, that would trigger the mouse event which would then trigger... Anyways, sorry for the amateur hour.

Happens to the best of us, glad you found a solution

As Preston Bourne said, you can use the appropriate event and then the position of the target instead of the one from the mouse.
// ...

  function handleMouseEnter(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getBoundingClientRect()); // position x, y of the target element not the mouse
    // manage your state (show true, use the x, y, etc...)
  }

  function handleMouseLeave(e) {
    console.log('leave');
    // manage your state when leaving 
  }

  return (
    <span onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}>
      test
    </span>
  );
}

